# Check Checkbox in GridView, if Database has value True

Tags: jquery, asp.net, database, checkbox

I have a Database Table called Student.Its Fields are :

```
Name Varchar(20),
IsActive Int(1).   // 1 for checked. 0 For unchecked.
```

I am adding this table into grid.

What I want to do is, 
All the related checkboxes of Gridview row should be  checked, If database record have IsActive = 1 value, else Unchecked.

Comment: Can you please show what you did so far and where exactly you are facing the problem?

Comment: Put the html of your gidview and how you are binding the data in gridview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind it like this in the gridview:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdStudents" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
     <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
          <asp:TemplateField>
              <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:CheckBox ID="chkIsActive" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("IsActive").ToString() == "1" ? true : false %>' />
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```